# `fuse`-like mounts on linux-vserver/openVZ?

Tags: ssh, mount, openvz, fuse, linux-vserver

I don't know much about servers or virtualization. However, for the last years, I've been using a rented linux-vserver as my backup drive and for recording radio shows through cronjobs.

I ran out of disk space at this provider and always wanted a proxy in the US, so I'm thinking of this [100G openVZ offer](http://www.lowendbox.com/blog/reliable-hosting-services-768mb-ram-100gb-disk-openvz-vps-for-5month-in-baltimore-maryland/).

I know I can't use lovely fuse inside the linux-vserver to mount the new box. This would be my preferred solution as it allows me to integrate everything seamlessly. Also [openVZ](http://openvz.org/FUSE) by default doesn't allow this.

Is there a way to configure my servers such that their combined disk space shows up in a single location?

Comment: Side note: My linux-vserver doesn't provide `/dev/fuse`, so it doesn't have the kernel module `fuse` loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally your OpenVZ provider only needs to enable the FUSE device `/dev/fuse` for your container. This is handled more-or-less the same way enabling TUN/TAP support is. Just open a ticket to the provider to have them enable it.

Or if you want things to work out of the box, skip OpenVZ (how do I hate thee, let me count the ways) and use Xen or KVM.

Comment: I just saw that my current linux-vserver provider also offers KVM w/fuse. Perhaps I should switch, but it's twice as expensive...

Comment: That's because with KVM they can't pack you in like sardines (oversubscribe) quite so easily. So you may pay more, but you do get a more reliable service.

Answer (score 0):

Overselling is overselling on any platform and it can be done on KVM as much as OpenVZ.  It all depends on your hosting provider and how much "overselling" they do, as long as the provider does a reasonable job of regulating fair usage of their resources.

The 'over'selling is the subjective part and how much $/resource the provider is trying to stretch out to cover X amount of users per physical server.

You can go to sites like serverbear.com and see numerous hosts and providers and sort them by various performance.  I also recommend sites like Web Hosting Talk and you can see what customers say about their hosting provider.

I am paying $10/month for an OpenVZ VPS with Fuse, with 30 Gig SSD drive, 1 Gig RAM, Quad Core CPU and 3TB of data transfer with excellent performance.

Comment: You seem like doing SEO for that linked company. :(

Comment: This is pointless and irrelevant to the question